# SVG to top,mixing layers

Tags: svg, vector, z-index

How i can make my  object to be always on the top of the other  objects? Cause when they are on the same position they are mixing

```
<g  transform="translate(0,0)" id="line">
           <path
                  fill="#F7931E"
                  stroke="white"
                  stroke-width="5"
                  style="fill:#fff;fill-opacity:1;"
                  d="M0,0 H3v0h50z" />
          </g>
```

i have a lot layers like this. nd i want to have one with other color on top. But they are mixing. How i can move to top? Id ordering is not working for me

And is it possible to position a div element with the Svg object,or write around svg object?

InsertBefore is destroying the position

Comment: What do you mean mixing. Create a [mcve]

Comment: Elements that are later in the file, will be on top of earlier ones.  You can use `appendChild(newElement)` of `insertBefore(newElement, null)` to insert elements at the end.